# why we drop the last term in the Barone-Adesi Whaley formula

Tags: american-options

In this paper [Efficient Analytic Approximation of American Option Values](http://www.math.ku.dk/~rolf/teaching/thesis/B-AWhaley.pdf)

in the first several lines of page 306, the author dropped the last term in equation 11, he explained that when $T\to 0$, we have $f_K\to 0$, but I don't know why.

Can anyone explain it?

---

$\epsilon$ is the early exercise premium, and $T$ is the time to maturity. Define $K(T):=1-e^{-rT}$

write $\epsilon$ as $\epsilon(S,K)=K(T)f(S,K)$

the equation 11 is
$$S^2f_{SS}+NSf_S-(M/K)f-(1-K)Mf_K=0$$

Comment: If you write down the formula then we don't have to search the pdf for it ... e.g. I am too lazy ;)

Comment: @Richard I have updated my post :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is a hand-wavy way to reach the above result. I suspect there is a more elegant way to show it though.

The *early exercise premium* is defined as the difference between the American and European option prices
$$ \epsilon(S,T) := C(S,T)-c(S,T) \tag{0}$$
In the paper it is further rewritten as
$$ \epsilon(S,T) = K(T) f(S,K(T)) = \epsilon^*(S,K(T)) \tag{1} $$
for some function $K: T \to 1-e^{-rT}$ and where we have let
$$\epsilon^* : (S,K) \to K f(S,K)$$

From the above expression
$$ f(S,K) = \frac{\epsilon^*(S,K)}{K} $$
hence 
$$ f_K(S,K) = -\frac{\epsilon^*(S,K)}{K^2} + \frac{\epsilon^*_K(S,K)}{K} $$
We would like to compute 
$$ \lim_{T \to 0} f_K(S,K(T)) = \lim_{K \to 0} f_K(S,K) = \lim_{K \to 0} -\frac{\epsilon^*(S,K)}{K^2} + \frac{\epsilon^*_K(S,K)}{K} \tag{2} $$

To help us in our computations, we note that:

> As the time to maturity tends towards 0 an American option becomes *strictly equivalent* to its European counterpart (i.e. same price + same Greeks), hence we notably have:
>   $$\lim_{T \to 0} \epsilon(S,T) = 0 \tag{A}$$
>   $$\lim_{T \to 0} \epsilon_T(S,T) = 0 \tag{B}$$
>   $$\lim_{T \to 0} \epsilon_{TT}(S,T) = 0 \tag{C}$$

---

Using (A) and noting that
$$ \lim_{T \to 0} \epsilon(S,T) = 0 \iff \lim_{K \to 0} \epsilon^*(S,K) = 0 $$
 we can rewrite (2) using l'Hôpital rule as

$$ \lim_{K \to 0} f_K(S,K) = \lim_{K \to 0} -\frac{\epsilon^*_K(S,K)}{2K} + \frac{\epsilon^*_K(S,K)}{K} = \lim_{K \to 0} \frac{\epsilon^*_K(S,K)}{2K} \tag{3} $$

---

From (1) $$\epsilon_T(S,T) = \epsilon^*_K K_T = \epsilon_K^*(S,K(T)) re^{-rT} $$
Using (B) along with the above equation yields
$$ \lim_{T\to 0} \epsilon_T = 0 \iff \lim_{T \to 0} \epsilon_K^*(S,K(T)) r = 0 $$
hence $$ \lim_{K \to 0} \epsilon_K^*(S,K) = 0 \tag{4} $$
Plugging this into (2) and using l'Hôpital rule gives 
$$ \lim_{T \to 0} f_K(S,K(T)) = \lim_{K \to 0} \frac{\epsilon^*_{KK}(S,K)}{2} $$

---

From (1)
$$ \epsilon_{TT}(S,T) = \epsilon^*_{KK} K_T^2 + \epsilon_K^* K_{TT} $$
Simarly to what we did earlier, using (C) along with (3) will lead to 
$$ \lim_{K \to 0} \epsilon^*_{KK} = 0 \tag{5} $$
and plugging that back into our expression for $\lim_{T\to 0} f_K$ finally yields
$$ \lim_{T\to 0} f_K =  \frac{1}{2} \lim_{K \to 0}\epsilon^*_{KK}(S,K) = 0$$